# How to retrieve value from server and save it in sqlite and to display it instantly?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-volley

I am having one doubt am fetching records from server using volley and saving it in SQLite and setting adapter by querying getlist but it is not displaying the result instantaneously I need to go back and come again to see the newly updated data how to display that record instantly after inserting it in SQLite let me post my code:

Here is the volley code for fetching records from server:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], new JSONObject(),
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String server_response = response.toString();
            try {
                JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("AccountPageLoadAccountListResult"));
                for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                    Model_Account modelobjs = new Model_Account();
                    JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    modelobjs.setCompany_group(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                    modelobjs.setState(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Region"));
                    account_sf_db.InsertorUpdate(modelobjs);


                }
            }  catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
```

Here is the adapter where am setting adapter from sqlite android:

```
List<ModelClass>listobj=new Arraylist<Modelclass>();
listobj=account_sf_db.list();
accountListAdapter = new AccountListAdapter(listobj, getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(accountListAdapter);
```

The purpose for this is to handle offline capability even during offline we must access it using SQLite.

Comment: what is the lenth of total data

Comment: around 10 each time when user press button it will communicate with server fetch new records

Comment: Are you calling the "notifyDataSetChanged" method of the adapter after the update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating your database table in Sqlite you need to add a `notifyChange` with the URI associated with the database table.

Here's an example how I did it in my code.

I had to declare a URI for my database table like this:

```
// These are just some constants
public static final String DB_NAME = "mydatabase";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String ApplicationPackage = "com.example.myapp";
public static final String DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS = "accounts";

// This is the URI of the database table
public static final Uri DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS_URI = Uri
            .parse("sqlite://" + Constants.ApplicationPackage + "/" + DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS);
```

Now when I'm creating a database table entry with a function, the function looks like this.

```
public void createAccounts(Account mNewAccount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        DataBaseOpenHelper dOpenHelper;
        dOpenHelper = new DataBaseOpenHelper(context,DB_NAME,DATABASE_VERSION);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("account_name", mNewAccount.getAccountName());
        values.put("account_number", mNewAccount.getAccountNumber());
        db = dOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS, null, values);

        // Here you notify the change when the database is updated
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS_URI, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the **DataBaseOpenHelper.java**

```
public class DataBaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private int newVersion;
    private String name;

    public DataBaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name, int version) {
        super(context, name, null, version);
        this.newVersion = version;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table if not exists "
                + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS
                + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, account_number text not null, "
                + "account_name text)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Now when you query your database table from your `Activity` or `Fragment` you need to `registerContentOberver` in your `onCreateLoader` if you're using `LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks<Cursor>` like this:

```
Cursor cursor = DataHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getAccounts();
this.registerContentObserver(cursor, DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS_URI);
```

So you need to load the data again from your Sqlite database to reinitialize your `listobj` when response returned from the server. And then call `accountListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: can yu please explain it briefly

Comment: The answer is clear enough if you've worked with sqlite database before. Which part you didn't understand? It would be better if you could tell me that.

Comment: where to set adapter in this whether in oncreate or loadermethods

Comment: do we need providers for this implementations

Comment: You'll set the adapter in `onLoadFinished` and `initLoader` in your `onCreate` function

Comment: do  i need content provider or it can be done with sqliteonehelper class where i have written all queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106093/discussion-between-reaz-murshed-and-yog).

Comment: we also need to intialize the cursorloader right in oncreate

Comment: Hey Reaz do we need to implement custom cursor for if we are not using content provider or can i do in this way

Comment: while implementing this am facing skipping frames how to resolve this

Comment: Usually skipping frames occurs when you do not have any data to populate in the list. It doesn't do any harm by the way. What's your problem exactly?

Comment: am getting that surely that will affect my app preformance na?

Comment: Umm ... I'm not sure about that though. You can put a different question in SO about this to get help from others. But in my case, I usually ignore these messages.

Answer (score 2):

Add a method in adapter as

```
public void addModelClass(ModelClass modelClass){
listobj.add(modelClass);
notifyDataItemInserted(listobj.size()-1);
}
```

then in volley onResponse call this function after sqlite insert

```
accountListAdapter.add(modelobj);
```

Comment: during offine will this work even during offine it must display the value from sqlite

Comment: When you insert a record in  your sqlite ,then call this method. the adapter will adapt the view at the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [cursor loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) with [Content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: can we achieve this without provider because i dont want to use provider

Comment: you can try without provider,Not sure about the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
accountListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

just call this method and see the result.

Comment: i this you dosent understand the question i cannot view the data instantly after syncing with server